# RVM 1.9.1 & nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, rvm, yarv

Having trouble installing the nokogiri gem under rvm ruby 1.9.1.

```
gem install nokogiri
```

I'm getting ...

```
/usr/include/libxml2... no
libxml2 is missing.  try 'port install libxml2' or 'yum install libxml2-devel'
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

but i checked:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2
```

and i got:

```
Reading state information... Done
libxml2 is already the newest version.
```

is this a root thing perhaps? RVM runs everything in userspace.

Comment: http://blog.lostincode.net/archives/2010/1/2/installing_gems_with_native_extensions/ looks good

Comment: ah - on ubuntu its libxml2-dev not libxml2-devel

Comment: On Ubuntu I was suggested to do `sudo apt-get install ruby-nokogiri`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to confirm that the version of libxml installed by apt is current. Nokogiri likes nice fresh versions of libxml, so I built my libxml install from source.

nokogiri -v will tell you what you're using.

Comment: No problem. I ran into the problem SO many times I figured I should try to head it off at the pass for you.

Answer (score 10):

A simpler solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
```

Comment: Thank you! libxml2-dev is exactly what was missing on ubuntu. Works great to install nokogiri :)

Comment: `yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel` got it working on my centos box, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem using homebrew on Mac.

Here's the code that does the trick, a small extension of the Nokogiri installation instructions for homebrew.  Basically, you need to include a directive to tell nokogiri to use the homebrew libxml dirs.  Make sure you point to the correct version of libxml2 installed by homebrew, which for me was 2.7.8:

```
brew install libxml2

brew link libxml2 #this may be enough but didn't work for me with rvm

#explicitly tell nokogiri to use you homebrew libxml2 rather than system
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26
```